# Is it possible to step into ios framework code in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)loadView {
    BNRHypnosisView* view = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc] init];
    self.view = view;
}
```

I need to step into init->msgsend->init with frame. Is it possible.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the framework? If not, you can only see the assembly code.

Comment: since oc is open source, i guessed that i could attach some source code and magically i can step into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, yes, but as you don't have the source code, it won't mean much as it will show assembler and the occasional symbol.